# sas macro resolving issue

Tags: variables, macros, concatenation, datastep

Dummy data:
MEMNAME     _var1       var2         var3           var4
XY         XYSTART_1    XYSTATT_2   XYSTAET_3   XYSTAWT_4

I want to create a macro variable that will have data as TEST_XYSTART, TEST_XYSTATT, TEST_XYSTAET, TEST_TAWT.... how can I do this in datastep without using call symput because I want to use this macro variable in the same datastep (call symput will not create macro variable until I end the datastep).

I tried as below (not working), please tell me what is the correct way of write the step.

1. case = "TEST_"|| strip(reverse(substr(strip(reverse(testcase(i))),3)));

   %let var = case;      (with/without quotes not getting the desired result).
2. abc= strip(reverse(substr(strip(reverse(testcase(i))),3)));

   %let test = TEST_;
   %let var = &test.abc;

I am getting correct data with this statement: strip(reverse(substr(strip(reverse(testcase(i))),3)))

just not able to concatenate this value with TEST_ and assign it to the macro variable in a datastep.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do.  If that convoluted expression works then it means you are working with data in a dataset.  Why do you want to make a macro variable? What are you planning to DO with the macro variable?  You cannot use it to change the code in the data step you are already running, that code has already been compiled or else the step would not be running.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to locate a %LET statement in the middle of a data step.  The macro processor evaluates the macro statements first and then passes the resulting code onto SAS to evaluate.  So if you had this code:

```
data want;
  set have;
%let var=abc ;
run;
```

It is the same as if you placed the %LET statements before the DATA statement.

```
%let var=abc ;
data want;
  set have;
run;
```

If you want to reference a variable dynamically in a data step then use either an index into an array.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array test test_1 - test_3;
  new_var = test[ testnum ] ;
run;
```

Or use the `VvalueX()` function which will return the value of a variable whose name is a character expression.

```
data want;
  set have;
  new_var = vvaluex( cats('test_',testnum) );
run;
```